# How to reopen a Spring Socket from TcpConnectionFactory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-ip

```
@Bean
public TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean tcpFactory(LengthHeaderDeserializer deserializer) throws Exception {
    TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean fact = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
    fact.setType("server");
    fact.setPort(port);
    fact.setUsingNio(true);
    fact.setSingleUse(false);
    fact.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer());
    fact.setSerializer(new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer());
    return fact;
}
```

If an exception occurs in `deserializer.deserialize()`, then the socket is closed by the server.

Question:
how can I tell Spring to reopen the socket afterwards automatically?
Or else, how could I force a reopen myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just closes the current connection from the client - the server socket remains open waiting for new connections. The client needs to reopen his connection.

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood it completely.